# Handling wildcard expansion from a string array in a bash shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Following is a sample script that I have written

```
line="/path/IntegrationFilter.java:150:         * <td>http://abcd.com/index.do</td>"
echo "$line"          <-- "$line" prints the text correctly
result_array=( `echo "$line"| sed 's/:/\n/1' | sed 's/:/\n/1'`)
echo "${result_array[0]}"
echo "${result_array[1]}"
echo "${result_array[2]}"  <-- prints the first filename in the directory due to wildcard character *  .
```

How to get the text "* http://abcd.com/index.do " printed instead of the filename when retrieved from an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming bash is the right tool, there are a few ways:

1. disable [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) temporarily
2. use [read](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) with IFS
3. use the substitution feature of [bash expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Disabling expansion:

```
line="/path/IntegrationFilter.java:150:         * <td>http://abcd.com/index.do</td>"
set -f
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
result_array=( `echo "$line"| sed 's/:/\n/1' | sed 's/:/\n/1'`)
IFS=$OIFS
set +f
echo "${result_array[0]}"
echo "${result_array[1]}"
echo "${result_array[2]}"
```

(note we also had to set IFS, otherwise each part of the contents ends up in result_array[2], [3], [4], etc.)

Using read:

```
line="/path/IntegrationFilter.java:150:         * <td>http://abcd.com/index.do</td>"
echo "$line"
IFS=: read file number match <<<"$line"
echo "$file"
echo "$number"
echo "$match"
```

Using bash parameter expansion/substitution:

```
line="/path/IntegrationFilter.java:150:         * <td>http://abcd.com/index.do</td>"
rest="$line"
file=${rest%%:*}
[ "$file" = "$line" ] && echo "Error"
rest=${line#$file:}

number=${rest%%:*}
[ "$number" = "$rest" ] && echo "Error"
rest=${rest#$number:}

match=$rest

echo "$file"
echo "$number"
echo "$match"
```

Comment: It works for me and I will be using the second solution.Thanks Mikel!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ line='/path/IntegrationFilter.java:150:         * <td>http://abcd.com/index.do</td>'

$ echo "$line" | cut -d: -f3-
* <td>http://abcd.com/index.do</td>
```

Comment: Did not work Marc.The problem with wildcard happens when I split the string , assign it to an array and try to retrieve it from array and dispaly!.